# Paypal express checkout java

Tags: java, api, paypal

I'm integrating paypal express checkout on one website and I'm using PaypalFunctions.java that I've download in the customized example.

I've successfull called, in development environment, the ppf.callMarkExpressCheckout
and after login on Paypal page I've correctly reached my confirmation page where i catch the payerId from the request.

I can't understand if the process is complete or I need to make a further step to get money and end the process.
I have this doubt because the process and the methods name is quite different than the one described in https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/gs_expresscheckout/ and I don't receive any mail from paypal dev environment

Kind regards

Answer (score 1):

In express checkout , once the buyer comes to your return url after confirming the Payments from their account you need to call the "DoExpressCheckout" API using the token and the payer id you received on your return url . Until this step completes , No payment will be recorded and hence no emails will be sent out . You can check the documentation for "DoExpressCheckout " API here :

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/DoExpressCheckoutPayment_API_Operation_NVP/

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_ec-singleItemPayment-curl-etc/

Comment: Thank for the answer.
I add some informations about the Java implementation.
In PaypalFunctions.java correspondences are:
GetShippingDetails = GetShippingDetails and DoExpressCheckout = ConfirmPayment. This change in name was not so clear. Also the need to show further pages after the first confirmation in pp pages isn't so clear, in our site we show recap informations before the start of express checkout procedure.

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right, you don't know how pay pal gets back to you. Look for 'returnUrl' (and 'cancelUrl') in https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/gs_expresscheckout/ . That's URL pay pal calls on your application once the user authorized the payment on the pay pal site.

Comment: Dear BetaRide,
I've configured returnURL and cancelURL.
When user confirms on paypal, PP callback me on the right page.
Now my process is in this way.
1)I call PP and obtain token, then the PPF.java function redirect to PP
2)when user puts credentials and confirms, PP redirects to confirmUrl
3)I take the "payerId" from the request and I save it on db
I don't understand if I must take another step because in the picture on the page http://goo.gl/zEiox2 I see last two pages must be on my website.
When I obtain "payerId" have I finished?
Must I wait for a confirmation mail from dev environment?

Comment: No, you don't have to check mails.